# Db2 Database info wiped out after VM Restart in Azure

Tags: azure, db2-luw

I have done the Db2 11.1 installation on Linux 8.1 VM in Azure.
However, every time we STOP & START the VM in Azure, all the Databases, Schemas & Tables are disappearing.

NOTE : I have made an entry in /etc/fstab path of my filesystem & its mounting device.
This is to ensure that drive is remounted automatically after a reboot.

I am able to see my mount device when given 'df -h' command.

But all the Databases, Schemas & Tables data got wiped out.

How can I overcome this..

Comment: This points to a misconfiguration. You would need to share details about your configuration for someone being able to help.

Comment: Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sdc1                  128G  8.5G  120G   7% /datadrive3
/dev/sda1                  496M  199M  297M  41% /boot

Please see  /datadrive3

Answer (score 0):

I worked last month on azure with RHEL7.9  and DB2 11.1
we solved a similar problem with a systemd /etc/systemd/system/db2fmcd.service

not exactly matching our problem:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-autostart-not-supported-red-hat-enterprise-linux-version-7